# UIView resizing in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am wondering why I can't set value to view.Frame like I normally do in Swift. Right now I am working with C# Xamarin application and try to resize UIView but it didn't respond to any methods it always stay the same. When I try to change View.Frame

> "Cannot modify the return value of 'UIView.Frame' because it is not a
>   variable"

. I tried to change Frame of UIView that it could fit screen but this options doesn't work. How can I change frame of UIView that can fit every screen?

```
        public void NotchNavBarCreator(UIView bar, UINavigationBar barItem) {
           CGRect barfr = bar.Frame;
           CGRect baritfr = barItem.Frame;
           barfr.Width = this.View.Bounds.Width;
           baritfr.Width = this.View.Bounds.Width;
           bar.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassing the Frame variable, like so:

```
bar.Frame = new CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 123, height: 321);
```

so if you just want to change the Width, do this:

```
//create a rect based on the old values + the new width value
barfr.Frame = new CGRect(x: barfr.Frame.X, y: barfr.Frame.Y, width: this.View.Bounds.Width, height: barfr.Frame.Height);
```